# v7 getSupportActionBar() is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-support-library

I'm launching a new activity (`TVMPDFActivity`) from my root activity. I'm using Android Annotations, so this is how I'm launching the Activity:

```
TVMPDFActivity_.intent(this.getActivity()).start();
```

`TVMPDFActivity` is a subclass of `PDFPreviewActivity` which is a subclass of `ActionBarActivity`.

A NullPointerException is being thrown from onCreate in `PDFPreviewActivity` when I simply try to GET the ActionBar. On this line:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Here is the stacktrace from my code to the NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.getDecorToolbar(WindowDecorActionBar.java:248)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.init(WindowDecorActionBar.java:201)
    at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.<init>(WindowDecorActionBar.java:176)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.createSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:156)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:123)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:73)
    at com.my.app.PDFPreviewActivity.onCreate(PDFPreviewActivity.java:63)
    at com.my.app.TVMPDFActivity.onCreate(TVMPDFActivity.java:24)
    at com.my.app.TVMPDFActivity_.onCreate(TVMPDFActivity_.java:31)
```

Here are the onCreate methods of the various classes involved:

```
public class TVMPDFActivity extends PDFPreviewActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setContentView(R.layout.tvm_pdf_activity);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}

public abstract class PDFPreviewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // throws NullPointerException
        ...
    }
}
```

Why am I getting a NullPointerException from deep within the support v7 code?

Comment: can you switch the order of super.onCreate and setContentView in TVMPDFActivity

Comment: Yes. I had to refactor some of the code in the base class onCreate() into a separate method because it needed the contentView set. But after reordering those calls (and doing that refactor) the Activity was able to launch. This Activity worked just fine this way in the past with the v4 support library. Any idea why it crashed this way?

Comment: Please add that suggestion as the actual answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `super.onCreate`  before `setContentView` in `TVMPDFActivity` in order to give android the opportunity to initialize its internal state, before trying to access something that relies on that internal state. For `onCreate`/`onStart`/`onResume` call the `super` always as first statement